# Stuck trying to prevent duplicate users being created

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, authentication, mysqli

I cannot for the life of me find out what is wrong with this. It is probably some hidden rule or silly mistake. This code is meant to prevent users from creating the same user or same email twice but only works for the username. Am I missing something or is it just a silly mistake? I am using two if statements to try and achieve this (as noted by comments) but it is not working.

Thanks in advance

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['emailAddress'];


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $DBname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Login` WHERE `Username` LIKE '$username' AND `Password` LIKE '$password';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$emailDB = $row['Email'];
$usernameDB = $row['Username'];

// username validation
if ($username == $usernameDB)
{
    echo "Username '$username' is already taken!<br>";
    exit;
}
//E-mail validation
if ($email == $emailDB)
{
    echo "Email '$email' is already registered!<br>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: *but it is not working* Can you describe this a little bit more?!

Comment: Your query doesn't look like it's checking what you want. You really just need to count rows that match password or username. If there are any, you have a duplicate. You can use = for the query instead of like.

Comment: It's also generally considered bad practice to store plaintext passwords, but that's another story.

Comment: Your query will only return rows where both user name and password match. If they do, the code will exit with a 'user name taken' message. If either user name or password doesn't match your query will return no rows, your subsequent code will fail the tests and your error log will fill up with warnings and notices as PHP does it's best to handle the mess.

Comment: Instead of what you are trying to do, you should be using a UNIQUE index for the columns that you don’t want to allow duplicates for in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need another query :)))  :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Login` 
       WHERE `Username` LIKE '$username' 
       OR `Email` LIKE '$email';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$emailDB = $row['Email'];
$usernameDB = $row['Username'];

// username validation
if ($username == $usernameDB)
{
    echo "Username '$username' is already taken!<br>";
    exit;
}
//E-mail validation
if ($email == $emailDB)
{
    echo "Email '$email' is already registered!<br>";
    exit;
}
```

and you should better use:

```
"SELECT * FROM `Login` 
           WHERE `Username` = '$username' 
           OR `Email` = '$email';"
```

because if it not really equal, new user can be registered :-)